# Eigenvector of $T$ with $T : V \rightarrow V$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Show that for each $0 \neq v \in V$ either $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $λ = 1$ or $T(v) − v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $λ = 0$

I would just like some guidance on where to start and how to approach the question.
Thank you.

Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $C$ such that $T^2 = T$

Show that for each $0 \neq  v \in V$ either $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $λ = 1$ or $T(v) − v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $λ = 0$

Comment: Hint: $T^2-T=0$

Comment: BTW, note that that is not an exclusive OR. I.e. for some $v$ both conditions are true.

Comment: Please put the hypotheses  at the beginning of the post, not as an afterthought!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint tells the whole story. Because $T^2 = T$, for any vector $v$ we have
$$
T(Tv - v) = T^2 v - Tv = Tv - Tv = 0.
$$
This means that for any vector $v$ whatsoever, $Tv - v$ is in the nullspace of $T$.  Nonzero vectors in the nullspace of an operator are eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue zero.  So $Tv - v$ will be an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$ whenever $Tv - v$ is nonzero.  And if $Tv - v$ happens to be zero?  That means that $Tv = v$, which means (if $v$ is nonzero, as is assumed here) that $v$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$.

Note that there is no use of the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional or that $\mathbb{C}$ is the field.

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you! :)